# alignment of navigation menu within td of table and no border

Tags: html, css, navigation, alignment, containers

I was just wondering as I haved failed to do so, that, do I get the navmenu within table in promo box and centered at the top of white space and no border on the top center box/td/cell
Help would be great as it is important.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
* {
    margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px;
    }

#container {
    width: 100%; height: 1000px;
    max-width: 1440px; min-width: 1024px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    }

.bigbox {
    height: 1000px;
    background-image: url(images/photos/landscape-1440.jpg);
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    }

.promobox {
    width: 25%;
    height: 1000px;
    float: left;
    background-position: 50% 0%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    vertical-align: top;
    }

.promobox div {
    height: 200px;
    border-color: #FFF;
    border-style: none;
    }


div {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    }

div a {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px; right: 10px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    }

#pb1 {width: 25%;
    background-color: #E51837;
} 


#pb2 {width: 50%;
    background-color: white; 
}

#pb3 {width: 25%;
    background-color: #E51837;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    }


ul#navmenu, ul.sub1, ul.sub2 {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 9pt;
    }

ul#navmenu li {
    width: 96.6px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 0px;
    float: left;
    }
#navmenu ul {
display: inline-block;
list-style-type: none;
}   
ul#navmenu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    width: 96.6px;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    background-color: #2E2E2E;
    border: 1px solid #777777;
    border-top: 2px solid #777777;
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-face: Arial;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    }

ul#navmenu .sub1 li {
    }

ul#navmenu .sub1 a {
    margin-top: 0px;
    }

ul#navmenu .sub2 a {
    margin-left: 0px;
    }

ul#navmenu li:hover > a {
    background-color: grey;
    }

ul#navmenu li:hover a:hover {
    background-color: red;
    }

ul#navmenu ul.sub1 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 26px;
    left: 0px;
    }

ul#navmenu ul.sub2 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 97.6px;
    }

ul#navmenu li:hover .sub1 {
    display: block;
    }

ul#navmenu .sub1 li:hover .sub2 {
    display: block;
    }

.darrow {
    font-size: 11pt;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 4px;
    }

#navmenu {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0px auto;
        padding: 0px;
        position: relative;
}
.rarrow {
    font-size: 13pt;
    position: absolute;
    top: 6px;
    right: 4px;
    }

#page1 .link1{
color: grey;
border-top: 2px solid red;
}
#page2 .link2{
color: grey;
border-top: 2px solid red;
}
#page3 .link3{
color: grey;
border-top: 2px solid red;
}
#page1 {text-align:center;}h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    }



ul#navmenu, ul.sub1, ul.sub2 {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 9pt;
    }

ul#navmenu li {
    width: 96.6px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0px;
    display: inline;
    }

ul#navmenu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    width: 96.6px;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    background-color: #2E2E2E;
    border: 2px solid #777777;
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-face: Arial;
    display: inline-block;
    }

ul#navmenu .sub1 li {
    }

ul#navmenu .sub1 a {
    margin-top: 0px;
    }

ul#navmenu .sub2 a {
    margin-left: 0px;
    }

ul#navmenu li:hover > a {
    background-color: grey;
    }

ul#navmenu li:hover a:hover {
    background-color: red;
    }

ul#navmenu ul.sub1 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 26px;
    left: 0px;
    }

ul#navmenu ul.sub2 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 96.6px;
    }

ul#navmenu li:hover .sub1 {
    display: block;
    }

ul#navmenu .sub1 li:hover .sub2 {
    display: block;
    }

.darrow {
    font-size: 11pt;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 4px;
    }

#navmenu {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
}
.rarrow {
    font-size: 13pt;
    position: absolute;
    top: 6px;
    right: 4px;
    }

#page1 .link1{
color: grey;
border-top: 2px solid red;
}
#page2 .link2{
color: grey;
border-top: 2px solid red;
}
#page3 .link3{
color: grey;
border-top: 2px solid red;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="container">
<div class="bigbox">

<div class="promobox" id="pb1">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="promobox" id="pb2"><table padding="0" spacing="0" width="557px" height="100px">
<tr><td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#E51837"><img src="#" width="481px" height="187px"><br><img src="#" width="418px" height="96px">
</td></tr><tr><td><br></br><div id="page1">
<ul id="navmenu">
<li><a href="dropdown1.html" class="link1">hyperlink 1</a></li>
<li><a href="dropdown2.html" class="link2">hyperlink 2</a><font color="white"><span class="darrow">&#9660;</font></span>
    <ul class="sub1">
        <li><a href="#">hyperlink 2.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">hyperlink 2.2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">hyperlink 2.3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">hyperlink 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">hyperlink 4</a><span class="darrow"><font color="white">&#9660;</font></span>
    <ul class="sub1">
        <li><a href="#">hyperlink 4.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">hyperlink 4.2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">hyperlink 4.3</a><span class="rarrow"><font color="white">&#9654;</font></span>
            <ul class="sub2">
                <li><a href="#">hyperlink 4.3.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">hyperlink 4.3.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="dropdown3.html" class="link3">hyperlink 4.3.3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">hyperlink 5</a></li>
</ul></div></td></tr>       
</table>            
</div>
<div class="promobox" id="pb3">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *how do I get the navmenu...

Comment: and get td to go full width without border

Comment: Welcome to SO... You can edit the question and update it instead of commenting below, which is less likely to get any attention... woud be great if you can make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) illustrating the proble...

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague without [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) example. Please show us live example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

If you are getting white spaces in table on top of menu please set cellspacing="0" on table tag like this

```
<table cellspacing="0">
```

And to make your menu in the centre inside the table please use use `display: inline-block;` on `ul#navmenu li` and `ul#navmenu a` instead of float and put `text-align: center;` on ul#navmenu

Float element cannot be centre with margin: auto or text-align: centre that is why we have to change element behaviour to display: inline-block to stand each element next to each other and make it centre of parent element.